# Stop javascript counter once it reaches number specified in div

Tags: javascript, counter

I'm using code from a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QgrFq/) to implement a count up feature on my site. I like it because it allows me to target a number displayed in a specific div, and I don't need to specify that number in the javascript, which means I can use it on any page for any number I choose.

See the code here:

```
// basic class implementation
function myCounter() {
    // privileged property for iteration
    this.i = 0;

    // privileged init method
    this.init();
}

// defining init method
myCounter.prototype.init = function () {
    // reassign this
    var _this = this;

    setInterval(function () {
        // call this.countUp() using our new created variable.
        // this has to be done as this would normally call something 
        // inside this function, so we have to pass it as own
        // variable over
        _this.countUp();
    }, 500);

    clearInterval(function () {
        this.i == 
    };
};

// defining the counter method
myCounter.prototype.countUp = function () {
    this.i++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = this.i;
};

// create a new instance of our counter class
var counter = new myCounter();
```

The only problem is that it doesn't stop counting. I'd love to add some code for that myself, except I'm not familiar enough with javascript and have no idea where to start.

Is there a way to tell javascript to stop counting at the number specified in the targeted div?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I would recommend making an if statement if (this.i == whatever you want)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// basic class implementation
function myCounter() {
    // privileged property for iteration
    this.i = 0;

    // privileged init method
    this.init();
}

// defining init method
myCounter.prototype.init = function () {
    // reassign this
    var _this = this;
    this.timer = setInterval(function () {
        // call this.countUp() using our new created variable.
        // this has to be done as this would normally call something 
        // inside this function, so we have to pass it as own
        // variable over
        _this.countUp();
    }, 500);
};

// defining the counter method
myCounter.prototype.countUp = function () {
    this.i++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = this.i;

    // stop the timer
    if(this.i == 8){
        clearInterval(this.timer)
    }
};

// create a new instance of our counter class
var counter = new myCounter();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is working great, but is it possible to stop the count at the number specified in the HTML (using the id), rather than in the JS?

Comment: Actually, I just realized my previous request wouldn't be possible (I think) because #counter's value is being set to 0 at the start of the javascript. So, I made your code work by putting the number I want to count up to in a data-attribute, and then I created a variable:

var countLimit = count.getAttribute('data-attribute');

and used clearInterval on that. Thank you!